# Strange Receipe from the "Overload" magazine

Tags: c++, design-patterns, move

I came across this code in Feb 2013 issue of "Overload" Magazine. I understand the code provided, but completly I do miss it's purpose, neither the analogy with std:: auto_ptr and sparing alloc/ dealloc cycles. If someone could re-explain this "recipe" in his own words. The description is as this :

> Recipe #2 – Containers with ‘move’ semantics Recipe #2 is admittedly a
>   rather weird one, but every good cookbook should contain at least one
>   weird recipe, so here goes. In high-performance code, there are
>   scenarios, where you need to have a container which stores complex
>   objects (such objects including allocated storage etc.), but those
>   objects are only moved around and are never copied. Providing a copy
>   constructor for such objects can be either difficult (for example, if
>   such an object includes a file handle) or undesirable for performance
>   reasons (if such an object contains allocated memory, copying which
>   would be expensive). One common way to deal with this is to use some
>   kind of reference-counted pointer (or something similar to
>   auto_ptr<>); this is a viable option, but it has the associated cost
>   of extra allocation/ deallocation, and in really high-performance
>   code, this might be an issue. In such cases, an approach similar to
>   the following could help (rephrasing a proverb, you could say that
>   weird times require weird measures) – see Listing 2.

```
//class X is our complicated class
class StackOfX {
    // stack is just one example; any other type of
    // container (including maps, sets, lists, etc.)
    // can be written in a similar manner
    struct ShadowX { char data[ sizeof(X) ]; };
    typedef vector<ShadowX> ShadowV;
    ShadowV v;
    void push( /* move-in */ X& x ) {
        ShadowX& sx = (ShadowX&)x;
        v.insert( v.end(), sx );
    }
    const X& operator[]( int i ) const {
        return (const X&)v[ i ];
    }
    void pop( /* move-out */ X& x ) {
        ShadowV::iterator it = v.end() - 1;
        ShadowX& sx = (ShadowX&)x;
        sx = *it;
        v.erase( it );
    }
    ~StackOfX() {
        for( ShadowV::iterator it = v.begin();
        it != v.end(); ++it ) {
            X& x = (X&)(*it);
            x.X::~X();
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of the code appears to be able to copy objects that don't support copying, by treating them as sequences of bytes.

It's not a good idea to do that, but if it's to be done it would be more clear to use `memcpy` than a silly reinterpretation.

C++11 introduced support for move semantics. Before that, for C++03 there was Andrei's Mojo stuff (which however never took off). With move semantics support objects can be put in containers even if they're not copyable.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely obsolete with C++11, which provides syntax for move semantics directly in the language.

Get a book that's actually good and up-to-date, [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1090079)

To quote from that page: ***there are very many very bad C++ books***